# Creating an array from an array

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I want to resize an array. For example if I have an array with 10 elements, I want to exclude the first 5 elements, define another 5 elements from them, and assign the new ten to new array. Maybe I have the idea but I have a problem to define the new vector. Please find below what's in my mind.

```
Program test

Implicit None

Integer               :: i,j,k,m,n

Real,Dimension(1:20)  ::A

Real,Dimension(1:15)  ::B

Do j=1,20

A(j)=j+3

End do

 Do i=1,5

   Do m=1,3
    ! here, i want to define new array with 15 elements 
    ( A(i)+m*0.5*(A(i+1)-A(i)) )

   End do

End Do

End Program test
```

Comment: It is not clear to me, what you want as a result. Could you specify, how should the resulting array look like? Also, do you really want to *resize* array `A` or define a new array `B`?

Comment: Thanks for your respond, what i want to do exactly is to define a new array let's say B to A(i)+m*0.5*(A(i+1)-A(i)). I mean, i need to put this values as an array to use it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward extension of your code taking into account the information from the comment is the following, but your intention is really not that clear. It uses the first 6 elements of `A`, not 5.

```
Do i=1,5

   Do m=1,3

     B(3*(i-1)+m) = A(i)+m*0.5*(A(i+1)-A(i))

   End do

End Do
```

This code will make these assignments:

```
   B(1) <- A(1)+1*0.5*(A(2)-A(1))
   B(2) <- A(1)+2*0.5*(A(2)-A(1))
   ...
   B(4) <- A(2)+1*0.5*(A(3)-A(2))
```

Check if you really intended this order, it could also be `5*(m-1)+i`.

Comment: Thank you so much, last question please, i am confused how to write these vector on the screen

Comment: For example, when i wrote B on the screen and the vector is zero

Comment: `print *, B`  Please read some Fotran tutorial, it will help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake. Now it's working perfectly. Thank you so much for your help, i appreciate that. Have a nice night.